# Case statement with logic operators (< > =, etc) in Pascal

Tags: case, pascal

I'm having trouble making this work. Apparently, i can't use > or < in the case sentence, is there a workaround for this? Thanks!

```
case num of
    0:
        begin
            cont_0 := cont_0 + 1;
        end;
    > 0:
        begin
            cont_pos := cont_pos + 1;
            sum_pos  := sum_pos + num;
        end;
    < 0:
        begin
            sum_neg := sum_neg + num;
        end;  
    else;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case Sign(num) of
    -1: ... 
     0: ...
     1: ...
end;
```

More readable than `if ... else if ... else`? You decide.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use case then, why not use if?

```
if num = 0 then
        cont_0 := cont_0 + 1;
if num > 0 then
BEGIN
        cont_pos := cont_pos + 1;
        sum_pos  := sum_pos + num;
END
if num < 0 then
        sum_neg := sum_neg + num;
```

Comment: In the flow chart i used CASE, i like it more. Less bulky. Thanks anyway!